# While, if and else conditions

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-conditions

I have the code:

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($rst)) 
        if(($res)==TRUE)
         echo "$res[2]";
        else
         echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'>";
```

First echo it shows me output when I have results. 
Second echo doesn`t show the image when if condition is false. 
Any help, please? :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you checking `$res` as true in the if?  It will/should always be true within the loop.  Except in your code, you assign the first loop to false, when you have no results ... so because you are not properly checking before assigning it you get false on the first loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few formatting things I would fix that increase the readability

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($rst)) 
    if(($res)==TRUE)
     echo "$res[2]";
    else
     echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'>";
```

To this

```
while(false !== ( $res = mysql_fetch_array($rst) ) ){
    if($res[2] == true){ // or isset( $res[2] ) ?
         echo "$res[2]";
    }else{
         echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'>";
    }
}
```

Lets start at the top. `mysql_fetch_array`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php ~ returns an array or false.

Then we are evaluating it against false, and assigning it's value to $res.  Next the extra `()` around `$res` is meaningless, even checking true here **Likely your issue** is meaning less, it will never enter the loop as false, so inside the loop `$res` is never false.  Last addition of proper indenting and `{brackets}`.

In reality you probably intend this?

```
if( mysql_num_rows( $rst ) ){
    while(false !== ( $res = mysql_fetch_array($rst) ) ){        
        echo $res[2];    
    }
}else{
    echo '<img src="imagini/banner.png">';
}
```

In the equivalent PDO

```
if( $stmt->rowCount() ){
    while(false !== ( $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ) ){        
        echo $res[2];    
    }
}else{
    echo '<img src="imagini/banner.png">';
}
```

Pleas note mysql_* family of functions are depreciated as of PHP5.5
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Comment: @Emz - yes there is that little detail

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu - glad I could help.  As Emz stated, mysql_ family of functions are depreciated, which means they will be removed from php ( I think in PHP 7 ) if your learning PHP then I would look at PDO or mysqli but PDO is the preferred way these days.

Comment: I understand. Indeed I am a learner and I am creating a user interface for my team.

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu - cool, we all have to learn new things, I am still learning new things with programing in general and PHP too.  That said, I would spend time learning PDO instead, as stated mysql_* will be removed at some point.  It's important too to learn the history of the PHP language, and to keep an eye on new features, removal of old features and development of the language, if your really serious about doing PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the relative path is at fault here. Make sure that is correctly set.

**EDIT**

While the path thing might be a problem, it is not the biggest here.

What you most probably want is either:

```
// this tests if there are zero or more rows in your result
if (mysql_num_rows($rst)==0)
{
    echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'/>";
}
else
{
    while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($rst))
    {
         echo $res[2];
    }
}
```

or

```
// this tests, for each row, if a column is set or not
while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($rst))
{
    // index is the index of the column that can be set or not
    if (empty($res[index]))
    {
        echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'/>";
    }
    else
    {
         echo $res[2];
    }
}
```

Also, you seem to retrieve `<img>` tags from the database, since you have an default `<img>` tag as an alternative. If `$res[2]` has this pattern `<img src='some_path'/>` maybe you can modify the content of the database to keep just the relative path (without the tag) and echo the tag in the while loop.

Comment: I tried also echo "TEXT"; at the second echo, just to verify and it doesn`t work. Thanks for quick reply. :)

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu What does your if actually test? $res should be true always in your situation (since the loop will not execute when $res is set to FALSE or equivalent values). Maybe you want to test that some element of $res is set (or TRUE).

Comment: My IF tests if my database has a value adeed in a column. If it has, it has to show another value from that row. If the value tested is not present, the second echo must show a picture.

Comment: I tried
if (!$rst)
{
    echo "TEXT";
}
else
{
    while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($rst))
    {
         echo "$res[2]";
    }
}
And it still does not show me the TEXT if no value found in DB. 
If I have value, the second echo works.

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu Try the second piece of code that I provided. Maybe that is what you want.

Comment: Strange. The second code return me blank page. I checked the code and looks ok.

Comment: @BogdanConstantinescu Did you replace index with the index of the column in your result?

Comment: No, this is the code that worked:
if( mysql_num_rows( $rst ) ){
    while(false !== ( $res = mysql_fetch_array($rst) ) ){        
        echo $res[2];    
    }
}else{
    echo '<img src="imagini/banner.png">';
}

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the if and else so you can see if it has something to do with what your outputting or if it is failing to reach the else.

```
    if(($res)==FALSE)
     echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'>";
```

Comment: I did the next switch and it shows me the image: if(($res)==TRUE)  echo "<img src='imagini/banner.png'/>";

Comment: Most likely is failing to reach else condition.

Comment: np, only if it help a little